# Calling the method of a casted object in obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting

I have a feeling that this will be a very quick answer. I'm doing Paul Hegarty's Stanford course on iOS development and he is mentioning casting. I have some experience with Java but have not encountered casting so I guess this could be a general question about casting too. I just can't seem to find a succinct explanation online. The code he gives is:

```
@interface Vehicle
- (void)move;
@end
@interface Ship : Vehicle
- (void)shoot;
@end

Ship *s = [[Ship alloc] init];
[s shoot];
[s move];

Vehicle *v = s;
[v shoot];

id obj = ...;
[obj shoot];
[obj someMethodNameThatNoObjectAnywhereRespondsTo];

// I understand up to this far, but it's the casting I'm having difficulty with

NSString *(hello) = @"hello";
[hello shoot];
Ship *helloShip = (Ship *)hello; 
[helloShip shoot];
```

So in the first line he creates a pointer to NSString called hello. In the second line he calls the shoot method of hello, which is an NSString, and that method doesn't exist so that won't work.
In the third line he is creating a pointer to a Ship object called helloShip, and setting it equal to what? an NSString pointer converted(casted?) to a ship pointer? If that's the case, why does calling shoot fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting does not convert an object to a different kind of class. It just makes the compiler to treat a certain object as if it was that kind of type (Hermanns example nails it).

In your example `hello` is of `NSString *` type. Casting it to `Ship *` and calling its `shoot` method will compile - and crash.

Even after casting `hello` is still a `NSString *`.

That doesn't mean that casting is useless. Take an array or example. Compiler doesn't know
what `[anArray objectAtIndex:x]` will return unless you cast the result to a (correct) type.

Another example would be:

```
-(void)objectTapped:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
      UIButton *aButton = (UIButton *)sender;
      //use all UIButton methods and properties
    }
    else if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
      UILabel *aLabel = (UILabel *)sender;
      //use all UILabel methods and properties
    }
}
```

So casting can be very useful but also dangerous if not used properly.

Comment: OK, so my main issue was around the function of casting - it doesn't actually convert the object, it changes how the compiler treats it.. If that's the case, what are the benefits of casting?

Comment: will add that to my answer

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks. Maybe too broad a question, but is there much scope for using casting outside of when you want to use id?

Comment: Yes. Casting is very useful in all the cases when compiler has no other means to know what kind of an object is dealing with. Delegate methods for example. If you know (or check run-time with `isKindOfClass`) that a sender is a `UIButton` you can cast a sender to `(UIButton *)` and that allows you to use a full set of `UIButton` methods and properties.

Comment: Downcasting (casting into a subclass) is a bit more common in ObjC than elsewhere because ObjC has no generics. This should not be considered a feature. I'm a big fan of ObjC, but this is a significant weakness in the language. Casting is dangerous and should be avoided when possible. It's just that ObjC creates a number of situations where it is necessary. Use it with care.

Answer (score 4):

Casting does not actually change the class of an object nor does it reformat anything of/within the casted object.

Casing only tells the compiler "Shut up! I am the programmer in charge and I know what I am doing. Eat it and compile it and let it run."

That's it. Not less than that and not more than that. By doing so it is your responsibility to ensure that the objects are well capable of respoinding to the messages sent.

However, with ARC your sample would not even comile. You cannot simply send `shoot` to an object of type `Vehicle`, because the `Vehicle` class and its objects do not respond to `shoot`.

Without ARC around you can send any message to each object and hope that the object responds to it on runtime. 
Your example code would run so far because the object that was assigned (and casted) to `v` is still of type `Ship` which does respond to `shoot`.

`NSString` will never ever respond to `shoot` regardless how often you cast it to what ever you want. (Unless of course you extend `NSString` with a category that implments `shoot`. But that is a different topic.)

Comment: I like the way you explained this.

Comment: Thanks :-) I hope it is understandable though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe I missed something here, but what is ARC?

Comment: Apologies. ARC stands for Automatic Reference Counting. It is an alternative method of managing memory. For most programmers it is easier ans less error prone but it comes with limitations. One of these is that you must stick to naming conventions for methods and must not call "undefined" methods.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't work, you are trying to something like below

```
int age=(int)@"My age is 60";
```

That doesn't work.

It has to be of that type for typcasting, in your case the you are trying to typecast `NSString *` to `Ship` both are different by meaning. So it won't work.